# Serial port connection problem

Tags: raspbian, usb, serial

I have to communicate to a device which uses serial interface through the USB port.
I disabled the Serial Port Login and disabled the Bootup Info. When I list the devices using lsusb, the device is detected.  ls /dev/tty* lists a number of tty , but no ttyUSB is listed. There is no change in the list before and after I connect to the device. ttyAMA0 is listed before and after the device is connected.
In the window PC the device is detected in COM5. How do I know the port to which it is connected. I have a java application that sends and receive data to the device.

dmesg | grep usb gives
 [ 3732.485108] usb 1-1.5: Product: ROTOR-GENE

[ 3732.485126] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs [ 3732.485142] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 120876

The device link is
 qiagen.com/us/shop/automated-solutions/sample-prep/rotor-gene-q

The device is connected to the USB port though internally the USB interface is connected to a USB-to-UART bridge.For programming purposes this means that the interface appears as (virtual) serial interface (RS232).

Comment: Can you get us device link ? Looks like driver is not available in built. You will have to install it manually.

Comment: Compare `tail /var/log/syslog` immediately before and after you plug in the device.

Comment: Also post output of `lsusb`. You device must be listed there.

Comment: You do not need to disable serial port login and boot messages.  They only appear on /dev/ttyAMA0 which is the gpio base serial UART.  No need to do anything special for serial over USB.

Comment: A thought.  Are you actually talking about a USB dongle plugged in to a PC connected to the Pi's gpios.  If that's the case you are using /dev/ttyAMA0.  A photo of your set-up would help.